# Example of a series that is convergent for all $k$ but not absolute convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Anyone have a example of a series $\sum a_{n}$ so that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$  $\sum a_{n}^{k}$ converges conditionally but fails to converge absolutely?

Comment: At least there is no real sequence, since $a_{n}^{2} ≥0$

Comment: but it can be a complex serie

Comment: I guess you are looking for something like $a_n = e^{in}/\log(n+2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a_n = \tfrac {\Bbb e ^{\Bbb i n}} {\log n}, \ n \ge 2$ (we take $n \ge 2$ in order to avoid problems in the denominator). Then for every $N \in \Bbb N \ge 2$, using the formula for the sum of a geometric progression, we have

$$\left| \sum \limits _{n=2} ^N \Bbb e ^{\Bbb i kn} \right| = \left| \frac {1 - \Bbb e ^{\Bbb i k(N-1)}} {1 - \Bbb e ^{\Bbb i k}} \right| \le \left| \frac 1 {1 - \Bbb e ^{\Bbb i k}} \right| + \left| \frac {\Bbb e ^{\Bbb i k(N-1)}} {1 - \Bbb e ^{\Bbb i k}} \right| = \frac 2 {|1 - \Bbb e ^{\Bbb i k}|} ,$$

so $\left| \sum \limits _{n=1} ^N \Bbb e ^{\Bbb i kn} \right|$ is bounded with respect to $N$. Since $\tfrac 1 {\log n} \to 0$, we may apply [Dirichlet's convergence test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Dirichlet.27s_test) to conclude that $\sum a_n$ converges.

On the other hand, $\sum |a_n|^k = \sum \tfrac 1 {\log^k n}$, which clearly diverges, because for $n$ sufficiently large we have $\log^k n \le n$, so $\sum \tfrac 1 {\log^k n} \ge \sum \tfrac 1 n = \infty$. (Of course, we assume $k \ge 1$.)

Comment: but $\sum |a_{n}^{k}|=\sum 1/n^k $ that converges for $k >1$

Comment: Sorry, i've edited my post, thanks for the advice

Comment: This was posted 14 minutes after Sangchui made a comment suggesting the same approach, so I think a mention of that comment is in order in your post.

Comment: @zhw.: What you say was written in a comment of mine (now deleted) "between" the OP's two comments above (part of that discussion has been deleted as obsolete). Initially I had posted a different answer, due to some ambiguity in the OP's original question. After the discussion with the OP, I changed my answer to reflect the change in his question. In no way is my answer influenced by Sangchul Lee's one - for me, it is the only solution that I could think of (what other function $f(n)$ has its powers weaker that $n$? $\log$ is the only thing that I can think about).

Comment: @zhw.: In any case, I was reluctant about posting this answer, precisely for these ethical reasons. Nevertheless, looking at the edit history for both my answer and for the original question, you will see that I worked completely independently from Sangchul Lee (even though this happend a bit after he posted his comment). Essentially, my thought was: what complex series should I choose in order to apply Dirichlet's test? A bit of experience with the subject helped me find my way. Anyway, *I've never stolen ideas from others, let me say this very clearly*.

Comment: Not saying you stole anything. I just thought a mention was in order, that's all.